# GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Enemy").Length off by one for some reason?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

so I'm wanting to pause the game once the amount of enemies hits 0. So I'm using GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Enemy").Length to find the number of enemies. I put this in a function that's called right when the enemies are instantiated so I can see the length go to 4, as there's 4 enemies spawning. When an enemy is killed the function is called again where the length is printed to console again. For some reason, on the first enemy killed the count repeats with a 4 again despite there only being 3 enemies. Once another enemy is killed it reports 3 when there's actually 2 and so on until I get to 1 when there's 0 enemies.

Here's the first snippet of code:

```
    public class EnemyList : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<GameObject> weakMobs = new List<GameObject>();
    public List<GameObject> mediumMobs = new List<GameObject>();
    public List<GameObject> bossMobs = new List<GameObject>();
    public List<Transform> spawningChildren = new List<Transform>();
    public static int mobCount;

    void Start()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < spawningChildren.Count; i++)
        {
            GameObject newWeakMob = Instantiate(weakMobs[0], spawningChildren[Random.Range(0, 4)]) as GameObject;
        }
        
        CheckMobCount();
    }
    public void CheckMobCount()
    {
        mobCount = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Enemy").Length;
            print(mobCount);

}
```

The next piece of code is where the enemy is killed and the CheckMobCount() is called again.

```
public void TakeDamage()

{
    enemyCurrentHealth -= 25;
    enemyHealthBar.SetHealth(enemyCurrentHealth);
    if (enemyCurrentHealth == 0)
    {
        Destroy(this.gameObject);

        enemyList.CheckMobCount();
        //needs death animations
    }
}
```

Here's the console messages:
[Console of printed lengths](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fFEK.png)

I'm self taught so I apologize if this is elementary. I've tried doing this several different ways and this is the closest I've been but I'm open to new ideas as well.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have attached your script to your enemy instances. And they are still alive when you are querying for the number of enemies left.

You should do the following:

```
public class Enemy: MonoBehaviour
{
       public static int EnemyCount = 0;
       
       private void Start()
       {
           EnemyCount++;
       }
       private void OnDestroy()
       {
          EnemyCount--;
       }
}
```

And then you can query the enemy count from anywhere but just excessing the EnemyCount by Enemy.EnemyCount.

If you want to get a more difficult example then you can check out this Game Dev tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LPBRLg4c5F8&t=134s

Comment: I did end up editing my static variable to work properly similar to how you have here, I was over complicating it the first time I tried it and your comment helped me realize it just needed to be dumbed down a bit so thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

As noted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68093145), the object is not actually destroyed in the current frame.

From [the documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html):

> The object obj is destroyed immediately after the current Update loop… Actual object destruction is always delayed until after the current Update loop, but is always done before rendering.

I also agree that using `DestroyImmediate()` is a bad idea.

Ultimately, your question seems to really be about pausing the game when the enemy count reaches 0, which unfortunately hasn't actually been answered yet.

In fact, you don't really need to do anything different except move the check for the enemy count to the *beginning* of the `Update()` method, and pause the game there if it's 0. Then you'll find that the component for the enemy has been destroyed at that point.

Presumably enemies are spawned before the update loop starts (i.e. before the first frame), but if not then you can use whatever logic you're already using to decide that new enemies need to be spawned, to detect the fact that you haven't spawned any yet and avoid pausing *before* the enemies have spawned.

Answer (score 1):

`Destroy` is actually executed at the end of the frame. There is `DestroyImmediate` that is executed immidiatelly but it's [not recommended](https://forum.unity.com/threads/so-why-is-destroyimmediate-not-recommended.526939/) to be used. What I would do is to add a field or a property to identify whether the enemy is still alive and then to check against it. Something like:

```
class Enemy : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool IsAlive { get; set; } = true;
}

public class EnemyList : MonoBehaviour
{
  //...
  public void CheckMobCount()
  {
      mobCount = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Enemy").Select(x => x.GetComponent<Enemy>()).Count(x => x.IsAlive);
      print(mobCount);

  }
}
```

And then:

```
public void TakeDamage()
{
  enemyCurrentHealth -= 25;
  enemyHealthBar.SetHealth(enemyCurrentHealth);
  if (enemyCurrentHealth == 0)
  {
      Destroy(this.gameObject);
      this.GetComponent<Enemy>().IsAlive = false;

      enemyList.CheckMobCount();
      //needs death animations
  }
}
```

This can be further optimized to store the `Enemy` somewhere and not use `GetComponent` every time but you get the idea.

Comment: My code was already set up for me to easily attempt a static variable to be used correctly but this was going to be my next attempt. If I run into something in the future this will most likely be how I do it as it makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned by others the issue is that [`Destroy`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html) is executed **delayed**.

> Actual object destruction is always delayed until **after the current Update loop**, but is always done before rendering.

You could simply count only the `GameObject`s that are still *alive*, those for which the [`bool` operator](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object-operator_Object.html) is `true`.

> Does the object exist?

It will be false for objects destroyed in that same frame.

E.g. using [Linq `Count`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.count)

```
using System.Linq;

....

mobCount = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Enemy").Count(e => e);
```

which basically equals doing

```
mobCount = 0;
foreach(e in GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Enemy"))
{
    if(e) mobCount++;
}
```

There is no need for an additional property or Component.

Comment: `.Count(e => e)` will not compile

Comment: @bashis yes it will .. why should it not?

Comment: Let's assume that @bashis is overlooking Unity3d providing an implicit conversion from its `Object` class to `bool` (frankly, a very odd design choice). Even so, calling `Count()` on a collection that already has a perfectly good `Length` property makes no sense. I fail to see what the above contributes to the question.

Comment: @PeterDuniho as said it filters out any objects from the list that are not alive anymore .. which is the case in OP's case since `Destroy` is used. This destroy is delayed though so Unity first so the object actually removed at the end of the frame while the bool operator will already return false for objects destroyed within that same frame .. it doesn't count all items .. that's the whole purpose of using `Count` with a predicate ;)

Comment: Thank you for this comment, I might switch to this method at some point but I got it working using a static variable for now.

Comment: @derHugo true, I completely forgot that Unity implicitly casts `GameObject` to `bool`.

Answer (score 0):

I am suggesting you to use “DestroyImmediate” instead of “Destroy”，Then look at the result.
I have a better idea, why not just use static variables when spawning enemies?

```
 void Start()
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < spawningChildren.Count; i++)
    {
        GameObject newWeakMob = Instantiate(weakMobs[0], 
        spawningChildren[Random.Range(0, 4)]) as GameObject;
        mobCount++;
    }
    
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

- Do not use Linq
- Do not use DestroyImmediate (it will freeze and bug your game, probably)
- Avoid FindGameObjectsWithTag in loops, only in initialization.
- Track your enemies in an array or list
- When you destroy an enemy, remove it's reference from the list
- Use the list count/length to get the real actual number.